# Powerpoint align equation at equal sign

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How do i align equations at the equal sign in powerpoint ? In microsoft word there is an option to align at the equal sign but I've spent 10 minutes and can't find a similar option for powerpoint.

Comment: HELP ? 50 POINTS

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In equation mode, write your equations one line at a time, hitting "shift+enter" to create each new line. After writing them, one equation at a time, right click on the left of the equal sign: in the contextual menu that opens, select "Math options -> Align at this character".

Comment: Nice! Btw if anyone struggles like me with centering the equations as a block thereafter: "Math options -> Centered as a Group" helps!

Comment: I don't see "Align at this character", only "professional" and "linear".

Comment: That has no effect in PowerPoint 365.

Comment: Wow this works perfectly for me. One key thing is you cannot select anything when right click. Just put the cursor before or after the = then right-click, the contextual menu will show "align at this character". If you select / highlight the = sign, it won't show the option, which is somewhat confusing lol

Comment: This doesn't work for me either in Powerpoint 365.

Answer (score 10):

As it seems, something similar to the `eqnarray` LaTeX command is available in PowerPoint 365 as `\eqarray`. For example, you could write

```
\eqarray(1+2&=3@3&=1+2)
```

which should present an equation in the form

```
1+2 = 3
  3 = 1+2
```

That is, the & symbol marks the sign used for the alignment (= in this example), and the @ symbol marks a new line.

Reference: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_winother-mso_2010/align-equations-at-the-equal-sign-in-power-point/3db2b789-aa08-49bd-939c-67e61250e367

Comment: Only problem I cannot format individual elements within these equations then.